# Azure Website/Visual Studio Online Continuous Deployment fails for Website

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-web-app-service, vs-web-site-project

I hooked up a Web Site project in Visual Studio 2013 to the continuous deployments within Azure Web Sites.  Checking-in triggers a build, but I receive the following error:

> Exception Message: The deployment package file (*.zip) was not found.
>   Ensure that PackageAsSingleFile msbuild property is not set to False.
>   (type FileNotFoundException) Exception Stack Trace:    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.Activities.FindPackageAndParametersFile.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

I added the msbuild argument for `PackageAsSingleFile=false` to the build configuration, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Matt, just wondering if you got anywhere with this? Thanks Russ

Comment: All, I know this is Matt's question but my issue is exactly the same.

Comment: "Ensure that PackageAsSingleFile msbuild property is not set to False".

It is instructing you to make sure that you don't set it to false.  Adding PackageAsSingleFile=False would further mask your problem.  Also, what happens when you set, `PackageAsSingleFile=true`?

Comment: Tyler, Yes I tried all this as none of it works. thanks for trying though.